# how to play video link generated by facebook API for newsfeed on safari browser?

Tags: facebook, video, safari, html5-video, safari-extension

I am php developer and using facebook api to get newsfeeds/livefeed from my facebook profile into my web application. I am able to get feeds with videos and able to play video on chrome/firefox browser but video is not playing on safari browser. I am using windows 7 64bit OS.

my code is

```
video id='mySampleMovie2' src='https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-prn1/v/t42/1555116_1377610509168076_1495472473_n.mp4?oh=37e226b7ab1adfedf02f8890c7c08ffe&oe=52DA4C2E&__gda__=1390020878_738cdcdc6eb7b81abaf7c4db87c345ab' controls></video
```

**how to play/embed facebook api generated newsfeed video on safari browser?**
sample fb newsfeed source link:

```
https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-prn1/v/t42/1555116_1377610509168076_1495472473_n.mp4?oh=37e226b7ab1adfedf02f8890c7c08ffe&oe=52DA4C2E&__gda__=1390020878_738cdcdc6eb7b81abaf7c4db87c345ab

https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-prn2/v/t42/1039326_1382677578661369_273818820_n.mp4?oh=c6bd4f5f9a2d072bd709d90b2a70e82a&oe=52DF7640&__gda__=1390385754_b924f0493f1da54afb74114076112bb3
```

Answer (score 0):

facebook currently uses flash so, if you have the URL you can embed a facebook video into your page using the following code

```
<object width="400" height="224" > 
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /> 
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" /> 
 <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  
   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224"> 
 </embed> 
</object>
```

check [this post](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-facebook-videos-in-web-pages/9715/) for more information

Comment: not working, actually i am getting feed video url by facebook api and the url format is not same as you describe in the example. news feed url give by facebook api is like - "https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-frc3/v/1547290_1375021499426977_366248905_n.mp4?oh=5b462cc42bf1be4dbc9e2798c14663bd&oe=52D5559C&__gda__=1389700875_09e1be7b4fcd6e8fa48c90b801c15f1e"

Comment: my above <video src...></video> code is working with given url but <object...></object> code is not.

Comment: another sample video link from facebook api feed is - "https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-prn1/v/t42/1555116_1377610509168076_1495472473_n.mp4?oh=37e226b7ab1adfedf02f8890c7c08ffe&oe=52DA4C2E&__gda__=1390020878_738cdcdc6eb7b81abaf7c4db87c345ab"

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Embed Url http://www.facebook.com/v/XXX is not working anymore because of a new facebook page http://www.facebook.com/v/

But You can still use this:

> https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=XXX

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe tag to play facebook video on an external website.

```
 <iframe src="https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-prn1/v/t42/1555116_1377610509168076_1495472473_n.mp4?oh=37e226b7ab1adfedf02f8890c7c08ffe&oe=52DA4C2E&__gda__=1390020878_738cdcdc6eb7b81abaf7c4db87c345ab" 
    width="420" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```